# How to get a property of a DynamicResource in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `Brush` defined in a code file and I am able to reference it using the `DynamicResource` extention in XAML at runtime. What I would like to do is to grab the `Brush.Color` and bind it to an element.

I've tried the approach bellow,

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ButtonHoverTopBrush.Color}" Opacity="0" />
```

but it doesn't work. How grab that `Color`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource ButtonHoverTopBrush}}"
                 Opacity="0" />
```

It doesn't work with `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource` but if you change the `Color` of `ButtonHoverTopBrush` dynamically, it will affect the above brush. You cannot replace the `Brush` itself though.

Comment: Ok got it, looks like a hack though.

Comment: @Themelis: It's binding to a property of a source. Not a hack but a standard binding procedure.

Comment: One question, what happens if `ButtonHoverTopBrush` hasn't being created yet? Or this declaration above forces the rercourse to be created?

Comment: @Themelis: Yes, it requires the resource to be created when the above brush is created.

Comment: If it hasn't being created does it throw an exception?

Comment: @Themelis: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mm8